# BATCH files: dynamic variable depending on the parameters

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a simple batch file

```
@echo off
set a1=application 1
set a2=application 2
set a3=application 3

set app = %%1%
ECHO %app%
```

What I would like to achieve is when I call my batch file (test.bat) with a parameter it would echo the desired string

so if I call:
test a1
-> application 1
test a3
-> application 3

DISCLAIMER: This is a simplified example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CALL set app=%%%1%%
```

note that batch is sensitive to spaces on `each` side of the `=`. You attempted to set a variable named app<kbd>Space</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
set a1=application 1
set a2=application 2
set a3=application 3
CALL SET app=%%%1%%
ECHO %app%
```

The `call` performs sonething similar to `eval`in eg. Perl, the `%1` gets replaced and then the statement `SET app=%a1%`gets executed.#
Without the `CALL` you end up with `%a1%` as value of `app`, instead of `application 1`.